# Azure CI/CD pipeline and Azure portal subscription problem

Tags: azure, cicd

I have one problem with my Azure. I created build pipeline, and now i want to set up relase pipeline. I choosen Deploy App service, where is located my app service with subsription and resource group..
In Azure subsription dropdown I choose my subsription, it is listed.. but I need to authorize myself. I click then on Authorize and I get this error..

```
Error(s):
Service connection creation operation failed
Error: Service connection with name Microsoft Partner Network (subscription number) already exists. Only a user having Administrator/User role permissions on service connection Microsoft Partner Network (subsription number ) can see it.
```

I guess it is problem with authorisation, but I cant figure what is problem. I have privileges for my resource group.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that within Azure DevOps a service connection with the name 'Microsoft Partner Network' already exists and that you do not have permissions to update/edit it. The permissions are actually needed within the Azure DevOps Project or Organization and are separate from Azure Resource Manager RBAC permissions such as are assigned to resource groups.

See [Service Connection security roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/about-security-roles?view=azure-devops#service-connection-security-roles) for the requires role and references to managing project roles in Azure DevOps

Comment: Can you give me more instruction about this ? What should I change and apply becaus eI am beginner ? Thank you so much !

Comment: [Manage Service Connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#edit-service-connection) is a good starting point. The info there will help you determine security settings for the service connection and if you do not have enough permissions to edit, then it will indicate who the creator of the service connection is so you can contact him/her to assign you permissions